# string arrays within objects within array

Tags: php, laravel

I am having trouble with a complex issue of stringing arrays within objects within arrays. My current code is as follows:

```
$responseCountInfo = $responseCount->data;

            foreach ($responseCountInfo as $macKey => $macVal) {

                $data['MacOrZoneID'][] = $macKey;

                foreach($macVal->walkbys_by_day as $key => $val){

                    $data['MacOrZoneID'][]['XAxis'][] = $key ;
                    $data['MacOrZoneID'][]['WalkbyTrend']['value'][] = $val ;

                }
```

What it outputs is:

> {
>     "success": true,
>     "data": {
>       "MacOrZoneID": [
>         "AC86744C4820",
>         {
>           "XAxis": [
>             "2016-10-03"
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "WalkbyTrend": {
>             "value": [
>               6555
>             ]
>           }
>         },
>         {
>           "XAxis": [
>             "2016-10-04"
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "WalkbyTrend": {
>             "value": [
>               6471
>             ]
>           }
>         },
>         "AC86744F96C0",
>         {
>           "XAxis": [
>             "2016-10-03"
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "WalkbyTrend": {
>             "value": [
>               2941
>             ]
>           }
>         },
>         {
>           "XAxis": [
>             "2016-10-04"
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "WalkbyTrend": {
>             "value": [
>               1934
>             ]
>           }
>         },

But I would like to group XAxis and values together instead of repeating them again and again like this

Also, I need the following format

`macKey` as array -> 1st level

`XAxis` and `WalkbyTrend` key as object and value as array -> 2nd level

> {
>     "success": true,
>     "data": {
>       "MacOrZoneID": [
>         "AC86744C4820",
>         {
>           "XAxis": [
>             "2016-10-03",
>             "2016-10-04"
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "WalkbyTrend": {
>             "value": [
>               6555,
>               6471
>             ]
>           }
>         },
>         "AC86744F96C0",
>         {
>           "XAxis": [
>             "2016-10-03",
>             "2016-10-04"
>           ]
>         },
>         {
>           "WalkbyTrend": {
>             "value": [
>               2941,
>               1934
>             ]
>           }
>         },

What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Try maybe somthing like this in second foreach loop

```
 foreach($macVal->walkbys_by_day as $key => $val){
    array_push($data['MacOrZoneID']['XAxis'],$key);
    array_push($data['MacOrZoneID']['WalkbyTrend']['value'],$val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$responseCountInfo = $responseCount->data;

            foreach ($responseCountInfo as $macKey => $macVal) {

                foreach($macVal->walkbys_by_day as $key => $val){

                    $data['MacOrZoneID'][$macKey]['XAxis'][] = $key ;
                    $data['MacOrZoneID'][$macKey]['WalkbyTrend']['value'][] = $val ;
                }
```

I think you are adding $macKey at wrong level. 
Try adding into inner loop and see if it works for you then :)

Comment: This would only give me in objects instead of arrays at the ``$macKey`` level.